# Delphi TDBGrid How to change selected color when style is gdsGradient

Tags: delphi, drawing, gradient, dbgrid

I'm just trying to use delphi XE, before that I've been a big fan of Delphi7.
I see the new dbgrid allows to use themed and gradient styles.

I'm using gradient and set rowselect, it has a property for gradient-start and -end for the column header.
But where is the property to set the `selected color` ?
It's strange because the color doesn't match, `selected color` is always a blue gradient.

I can do it with `customdraw`, I just want to know if there is anyway to change it without custom drawing.

Comment: `sory,my bad english ;)` Never apologize for that. Only 60 million people are native English speakers, the rest of us just struggle.  _Feels odd saying this whilst using US_EN spelling_

Comment: Perhaps it comes from the OS, as in clHighlight?

Answer (score 1):

The selected color comes from the OS.
There it's coded as `clHighlight`.

You cannot change it as such, but you can subclass the dbgrid and override the DrawCell method.
Or even easier add a `onDrawCell` eventhandler.

```
procedure TForm1.DBGrid1DrawCell(Sender: TObject, const Rect: TRect; Field: TField;  State: TGridDrawState); 
var
  index: Integer;
begin
  if not(gdSelected in State) then DefaultDrawCell(Rect, Field, State)
  else begin 
    index := ARow * DBGrid1.ColCount + ACol;
    DBGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clYellow; <<-- some color  
    DBGrid1.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
    if (gdFocused in State) then begin
      DBGrid1.Canvas.DrawFocusRect(Rect);
    end;
    ImageList1.Draw(DBGrid1.Canvas,Rect.Left,Rect.Top,index, True);
end;
```